# WPF Interaction.Triggers MouseDown EventTrigger Not Working with Canvas Element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, eventtrigger

I'm attempting to create an MVVM WPF application that allows me to draw a rectangle in the window. Right now, I've created a canvas element that covers the entire screen. Following other questions and guides, it looks like the only way to use command bindings on mouse events (such as `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, etc) is to use the System.Windows.Interactivity assembly and add EventTriggers for the mouse events. However, this doesn't seem to be working with the canvas element. Clicking, click/hold, click/drag, right clicking, none of them trigger the Execute method of my command.

What are the supported events for a canvas element? Why would `MouseDown` or `PreviewMouseDown` not be working?

XAML for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="RutheniumReader.SnippingWindow.SnippingShade"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:snippingWindow="clr-namespace:MyApp.SnippingWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Snipping Window"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Background="Black"
    >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <snippingWindow:SnippingWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Canvas x:Name="Canvas">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=MouseDownCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

For testing purposes, I've tried the following events with no luck:

- Click - works if I apply it to a `Button` element inside the canvas
- MouseDown
- PreviewMouseDown - works with a `Button` element
- MouseLeftButtonDown
- PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mouse events aren't working because the canvas's background isn't set.
If a control (in this case your `Canvas`) has no background color set, the background color will default to null, and that makes the control non hit-testable.

The background can be set either explicitly or through styles, and as long as it has a value different from `null` (even 'Transparent') it should pickup mouse events.

Comment: Yep, that works! Somehow I didn't think that applied since I set a background on the window.

Comment: That seems like a rather unintuitive operation. Good answer though

Comment: `Transparent` did not work for me (using a Rectangle element) so I set `Fill` to "#01000000".